# How can I know the docker launcher command from an exited container in CoreOS?

Tags: docker, coreos

I am using `CoreOS` as the host system and there are many docker containers running on it. How can I get the docker launch command for these containers? I searched there are some ways by installing third party library to do the reverse engineering work. But it doesn't work on `CoreOS` since I can only install docker container there.

The reason I want to know the launcher command is that I have a running container (this container was launched by some other scripts). I attach to this container and fork a process. The container will exit with 137 code if I kill that process. It works fine if I launch the container by this command: `docker run -it -d $NAME bash`. I am not sure why this happens. There must be something different with the launcher command.

Comment: Just `docker inspect <container-id>` and search for Entrypoint and Cmd. Isn't it enough? Also `docker ps --no-trunc`

Comment: the entrypoint is null from `inspect`. The output from `docker ps --no-trunc` is `/trampoline wait`. This doesn't tell me anything about the launcher command it is used.